# Eclipse content assist, there is no help during creating new object

Tags: java, eclipse

When I'm type in Eclipse Java Editor, something like:

```
List<String> list = new ..
```

After "new" I press Ctrl-Space but there are no Java Proposals related to implementations for "List".. so what I can see is just empty panel with message "No Java Proposals" or "No Java Type Proposals".

At the same time "assistance" is working for methods like:

```
System.out.
```

it shows possible methods.

This occurs in Eclipse Kepler and Juno builds, and I checked my Java-Editor-Code Assist settings but I couldn't find anything to help with this.

Comment: I have experienced it, when there is no active network. Check whether you have network properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Eclipse doesn't know about them until they've been imported.

As you said, the following won't do anything, because Eclipse isn't aware of what a `List` is, nor what implements it.

```
List<String> string = new ...
```

So we finish this off, grumbling a bit.

```
List<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And then we import the `List` class (not the `ArrayList` class). On the next line, we try again:

```
List<String> string2 = new ...
```

Now it offers us "List() - Anonymous Inner Type", which is a bit useless practically (it allows you to define an anonymous implementation of a `List` yourself). Starting it off with "A" doesn't help either.

```
List<String> string2 = new A...
```

Import `ArrayList` and try again:

```
List<String> string2 = new ...
```

Still no luck. But when you do:

```
List<String> string2 = new A...
```

It'll offer `ArrayList`.

**TL;DR: you need to import the non-system classes before it'll offer you content assist, and even then, only when you give it hints.**